# QT C++ - How to refer to a widget in another class

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make a button that adds a widget into a layout.

The widget is in another class entirely from the UI.

Normally I'd make a pointer to the other class (without the UI, with the widget) which would be `InkSpot *ink` (class name being InkSpot) then I would say `ui->paintAreaLayout->addWidget(ink->widget);` but that line right there causes the application to crash, if I remove it and add something not referencing that class then it wont crash.

I'll provide most of the code so that you can better see what I'm trying to do. The test button is at the bottom of the first code block which is the one in question:

inkpuppet.cpp

```
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"
#include "newdialog.h"
#include "inkspot.h"

#include <Qt>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QMainWindow>


InkPuppet::InkPuppet(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::InkPuppet)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //connect the frame range boxes to the timeslider
    connect(ui->lowerFrameBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setMinimum(int)));
    connect(ui->upperFrameBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setMaximum(int)));

    //connect the menu items
    connect(ui->actionNew, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(actionNew()));

    //connect test
    connect(ui->testButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(testButton()));
}

InkPuppet::~InkPuppet()
{
    delete ui;
}

void InkPuppet::setMinimum(int value)
{
    ui->timeSlider->setMinimum(value);
}

void InkPuppet::setMaximum(int value)
{
    ui->timeSlider->setMaximum(value);
}

void InkPuppet::actionNew()
{
    NewDialog *dialog = new NewDialog;
    dialog->setModal(true);
    dialog->show();
}

void InkPuppet::testButton()
{
    ui->testButton->setText("working");
    //ui->paintAreaLayout->addWidget(ink->label);
    //qDebug() << ui->testButton;
    ui->paintAreaLayout->addWidget(ink->widget);
}
```

inkpuppet.h

```
#ifndef INKPUPPET_H
#define INKPUPPET_H

#include "inkspot.h"

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class InkPuppet;
}

class InkPuppet : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit InkPuppet(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~InkPuppet();
    InkSpot *ink;

private slots:
    void setMinimum(int value);
    void setMaximum(int value);
    void actionNew();
    void testButton();

public:
    Ui::InkPuppet *ui;
};

#endif // INKPUPPET_H
```

inkspot.cpp

```
#include "inkspot.h"
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>


void InkSpot::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
    widget->setFixedSize(100, 150);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel();
    label->setText("test");
    widget->layout()->addWidget(label);
    //InkPuppet.ui->paintAreaLayout->addWidget(widget);

    QFile *brushInput; //takes raw 8 bit grayscale image, 8 bit values only
    char *brushProto;
    uchar *brushData;

    brushInput = new QFile("x:\\Development\\InkPuppet\\brush.raw"); //open the raw file
    brushInput->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QDataStream in;
    in.setDevice(brushInput);
    int size = brushInput->size(); //set size to length of raw file

    brushProto = new char[size];
    in.readRawData(brushProto, size); //read file into prototype
    brushData = new uchar[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        brushData[i] = (uchar)brushProto[i]; //copy char to uchar array
    }

    QImage test(brushData, 128, 128, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    QImage test2(128, 128, QImage::Format_ARGB32);

    QVector<QRgb> vectorColors(256); //create color table
    for(int c = 0; c < 256; c++)
    {
        vectorColors[c] = qRgb(c, c, c);
    }

    test.setColorTable(vectorColors);

    for(int iX = 0; iX < 100; ++iX)
    {
        for(int iY = 0; iY < 100; ++iY)
        {
            test2.setPixel(iX, iY, qRgba(255 - (qrand() % 100), 0 + (qrand() % 100), 0 + (qrand() % 100), qAbs((int)test.pixel(iX, iY)-255)));
        }
    }

    //final conversion for stencil and color brush
    QPixmap testPixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(test2);
    QPixmap testPixmap2 = QPixmap::fromImage(test);

    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.drawPixmap(150, 50, 100, 100, testPixmap);
    painter.drawPixmap(50, 50, 100, 100, testPixmap2);

    delete[] brushProto;
    delete[] brushData;
    delete brushInput;
}
```

inkspot.h

```
#ifndef INKSPOT_H
#define INKSPOT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QLabel>

namespace Ui {
class InkSpot;
}

class InkSpot : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit InkSpot(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~InkSpot();
    void draw(QPainter *painter);
    QWidget *widget;
    QLabel *label;
signals:

public slots:

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::InkSpot *ui;

};

#endif // INKSPOT_H
```

Comment: The same way you would refer to any other object member of any other class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I think, your error is in another place.
If you use pointers -- check them if they are not equal `NULL` every time you use.

I have not found initialisation of `ink` in your code. Please check it.

Also, from time to time do clean of your builds -- it can prevent some errors.

Comment: `InkSpot *ink;` in the header file?? I do clean up the build often.

Comment: Are you sure that your `ink` is initialized? For example, you may initialize it in `InkPuppet` constructor like `ink = new InkSpot(this);`

Answer (score 0):

This might be stupid, but what if you add the header, which contains the widget to the UI-class?
Or (re)define the widget inside the UI, so you can use it?

Try to add the header (with the widget's definition) to your UI-class, so the UI knows of the widget.
The definition is where you define the elements and functions (things you put in the header.

Or add the definition to the UI's header file, if you don't need the rest of the header's elements, but the first option would be better.

Comment: Sorry I'm still quite new to C++, how would I redefine the widget inside the UI?

Comment: I edited my answer, is it clear now?
With redefine I mean add the declaration to your UI's header file.

Comment: I don't know how to add the declaration to the header file, or what you mean by it more specifically. I have defined the widget in the external class, why would I need to define it again? It's already there, and if I declare it within the ui header, then I'd run into the exact same problem of trying to access it from the original class.

Comment: So, are you trying to get to a widget's definition, which is declared in another header? (Try including the widget to the UI class.)
Or are you trying to get a widget initialized in another class? (Pass that specific widget to your other UI class' function.)